# Rails string helper to remove hyphen and capitalize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know if there is a Rails helper method that removes hyphen from the String and capitalizes it.

For instance, let us turn `early-bird` into `Early bird`.

I would do

```
"early-bird".gsub('-', ' ').capitalize
```

but I would like to know if there is a specific method that does this.

Comment: @rockskull not a duplicate because the OP of that post wants the hyphens to remain

Comment: You right. I've put the wrong answer. Removed.

Comment: I don't think downvote was necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have pointed out, `titleize` is close to what you want.  But for the exact behavior you want you could just use your code to make your own helper.  If this is a view helper, you could put it in a helper file:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb

# my_titleize("early-bird") # => "Early bird"
def my_titleize(str)
  str.gsub('-', ' ').capitalize
end
```

or if you are using it in a model, make a patch.

```
# lib/patches/string.rb

# "early-bird".my_titleize # => "Early bird"
class String
  def my_titleize
    gsub('-', ' ').capitalize
  end
end
```

and then `require` the patch file in the model file.

Answer (score 10):

I think .titleize is the closest you get, it will capitalize all words though, not just the first.

```
'early-bird'.titleize
```

will give you "Early Bird".

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-titleize

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`titleize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-titleize) in Rails:

```
"early-bird".titleize
#=> "Early Bird"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `tr`

```
"early-bird".tr("-"," ").capitalize
#=> "Early bird"
```